# how to send mail from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
        mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("abc@yourserver.com");
        mailMessage.Subject =TextBox3.Text;
        mailMessage.Body = TextBox5.Text;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(TextBox4.Text));
        mailMessage.CC.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "abc@yourserver.com";
        NetworkCred.Password = "1234566";
       smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

---

### error

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.201.193.228:587

Comment: The mail server didn't respond to the connection.  There isn't much we can do about that.  You may want to work that out with whoever runs that mail server.  It's possible that you're not connecting to it properly.

Comment: Have you checked with your email provider to ensure the configuration is correct and the provider is not blocking any connections?

Comment: MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
 mail.From = new MailAddress(TextBox4.Text);
mail.Subject = "Recovery Mail";
mail.Body = "Hello " + TextBox3.Text + ", your recovery password is given below:" + "\n\nEmail: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n\nPassword: " + TextBox4.Text;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "123456");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 smtp.Send(mail);.......this code also gives me same error.

Comment: can you provide me how to send mail in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exapmple of how ASP.NET Identity messages can be sent, but you can use it for any purposes. It is using an external SMTP server to operate (gmail in this case).

```
 public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            using(MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.To.Add(message.Destination);

                mail.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountsServerEmail"]);
                mail.Subject = "Mobiler-registration";

                mail.Body = message.Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServerPath"];
                    smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServerPort"]);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                        WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServerRegisterCredentialsLogin"],
                        WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServerRegisterCredentialsPassword"]);// Enter seders User name and password  
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                    return Task.FromResult(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Change `throw e;` to just `throw;` With the former you lose the entire call stack, a very bad practice which unfortunately is very common. 2. `SmtpClient` is disposable as is `MailMessage` wrap them in a try/finally or using block.

Comment: If the error is still as you described in the question, make sure you have valid SMTP server  Host, Port and credential settings set.